# What's the adverb for the state of being panickily instantaneous?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

What's the adverb for the state of being panickily instantaneous? For example, when you play an action game, fighting a large bunch of enemies under great pressure, you just tap buttons ...ly in fear of losing the fight, while what you're supposed to do is be steady and calm.

Comment: *Frantically*, perhaps. There are plenty of alternatives.

Comment: Did you look up synonyms for panic in a thesaurus and branch out from there?

Comment: What does *panickily* mean, let alone "being panickily instantaneous"?

Answer (score 1):

You just press buttons *frenetically*, that is in a very agitated manner:

***[Frenetic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/frenetic):***

> - Fast and energetic in a rather wild and uncontrolled way.
>     *‘a frenetic pace of activity’*
> - frantic; frenzied.

ODO

Comment: This looks alarmingly like the question you asked in 2014, and the answer like Kris's there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - yes you are right, I forgot about that question, probably because my question didn't imply "panick" but just a very quick, possibly nervous way of typing. But why are you saying alarmingly?

Comment: Someone with 114k rep should surely know all the questions they've asked, all the questions ever asked on ELU, all the questions ever asked, all the questions that will be asked, ... and all the words not in OED.

Comment: @Edwin Askworth - Well, I've asked some 180 questions so far and this is about two years old.  Sorry I can't keep them all in mind to immeduamly recognize possible duplicates. In any case, as I said before, my question was different and the fact that some answers are similar does not make it a duplicate.

Comment: (I did alter the title of the duplicate to show the duplication, so I can appreciate that.) But I trust you _do_ know the 345 234 ... er 5 ... 6 words that OED doesn't list.

Comment: @Tonepoet - the adverb is in the first introductory sentence where it is placed within the context suggested by OP and its meaning is explained. The adjective definition is added because dictionaries, in defining  adverbs, generally  suggest  to look at the meaning of the relative adjective they are derived from.

Comment: @JOSH Ah, I see now. I missed that the first time somehow. Sorry for the bother. Perhaps this is trivial but maybe it'd be a good idea to make it bold so that it stands out more? Frenetic is bold and highlighted as a link, so it's more noticeable and perhaps a little distracting.

Answer (score 1):

> When you play an action game, fighting a large bunch of enemies under
>   great pressure, you just tap buttons ***desperately*** in fear of
>   losing the fight.

ODO:

> **[desperately](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/desperately)**
>   *ADVERB*
>
> **1** In a way that shows *despair*.
>   ‘he looked around desperately’
>
> ‘He desperately tried to get control of the car but crashed into a
>   lamppost.’
>
> **[despair](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/despair)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> [mass noun] The complete loss or absence of hope.
>   ‘in despair, I hit
>   the bottle’

Answer (score 1):

The game player is exhibiting [knee-jerk](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knee%E2%80%93jerk) reactions:

> occurring quickly and without thought
>
> often reacting quickly and without thought

(source: Merriam-Webster)

This originates from that test where a doctor strikes you gently on the knee with a special hammer, to gauge your reflexes.  It has become idiomatic for any action taken as if by reflex, i.e. a politician's knee-jerk answer to a reporter's question.

In your example, to say that you "just tap buttons knee-jerking-ly in fear of losing" would be a bit of a stretch, but it might work in informal registers.  A different re-phrasing would work better, perhaps "you just tap button with knee-jerk-like reactions, out of fear of losing."

Comment: Or, more broadly, you might call such actions "reflexive".

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions are good, but I'd also like to give "wildly" as a possibility.

Comment: Please explain our answer in full. Why would you like to give this as an answer?